# Changing text, font-color in TextBox Asp.NET

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, textbox

Hi i got simple 2 TextBoxes when i expect input from user. But i need got a default text in that TextBoxes with certain font-style. Plus logic of app should not proove this input. I using RequiredFieldValidator fot this purpose.

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3"
                             runat="server"
                             ControlToValidate="TextBoxName"
                             ErrorMessage="Error"
                             Text="Povinná položka!"
                             ForeColor="Red"/>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxName"
                     CssClass="textBoxName"
                     runat="server" 
                     Width="380px"/>
```

So when user see this default TextBox he should see something like "Name of item" so for this i use:

```
TextBoxName.Attributes.Add("value", "Name of item");
            TextBoxName.Attributes.Add("onFocus", @"if(this.value == 'Name of item') {this.value = '';}");
            TextBoxName.Attributes.Add("onBlur", @"if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Name of item';}");
```

But this solution dont work correct cause FieldValidator return true even user dont input nothing.
Should i use some simple maybe non-so-good secure technique and control default value with user input value? OR should i use databinding??? Or maybe some other solution? Im sure mayn people solve this issue in life at least one:D
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what i have understood is that you would like to have a text initially to help the user, also you would like to display validation error if the user didn't really type anything..

have you came across the attribute " Placeholder"? it does exactly what you want.
it is very straight forward and simple , here is an example:

```
 <input placeholder="enter your username" type="text" />

 <input placeholder="enter your Email" type="text" />

 <input type="submit" value="register"/>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YXrhC/

Comment: Thank you Saad, can i control this input control by RequiredFieldValidator ??? OK i did it:) Thanks a lot. Have a nice day

Comment: sure, one wat is to just use 
<%= RequiredFieldValidator.EnterTheTextPropertyHere %>
Or use a resource file for both the input and the requiredFieldValidator